# Why is it taking so long to open the Ubuntu Help Center?

Tags: gnome, yelp

When I click on the Help Center Icon in the 'System' menu, it takes more than a minute to launch the program. More than a minute, for a text only program seeming like a website!

All my other programs work fine, and I saw this problem also on other computers.

Is there a reason for this? Will it be fixed? I think it is an important issue for beginners.

Comment: My bad - I'm confused as to which "center" you were running.  Your output failed (I think) because it was already running btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably running into [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yelp/+bug/294182).

Comment: This has been fixed in newer versions of Ubuntu.